# Latex newspaper making - scribus render frames -

Tags: multicol, newspaper

I want to share here my efforts in newspaper making with latex. 
The latest try is using scribus and render frames. The success so far: 
partially register-true layout and the render frames that adjust multicols to the size  of the render frame - horizontally and vertically - the latter my achievement.

results here:
http://piquestions.com/latex/

- zpaper.sl.pdf:
  the result
- zpaper.sl.sla: 
  the scribus document
- 100_latex.xml: 
  the latex preamble file used by scribus, adapted for a3 format and with width and size adaption!!
- head.a3-scribus.tex: 
  additional latex packages and routines used

The whole newspaper making is semi-automatic. A script creates a scribus document with picture, title text and renderframe, including page headers. The rest is adaptation.

Comment: This doesn't seem to contain a question!

Comment: The OP states clearly that they want to share their effort of making newspaper with Latex. They don't ask any question.

Comment: So would it be legitimate in this exchange to ask "What efforts are needed to make a newspaper with Latex?" and then answer ones own question? For me such "sharing" is helpful and the OP has not pretended to be asking anything.

Comment: I should put the title as "can you have latex render frames that adjust the internal columns to the width and height of the frame?" and the answer then is yes ... the cool thing about this frame is that it adapts the content and decides how many columns should be used: if the width is small, it will  use one column but when bigger it goes to two, three... up to five columns.